# Is there any way to abstrat enums ValueSet?

Tags: scala, enums

I'm using scala 2.11, I have the following enums:

```
object Gender extends Enumeration {
  val male = Value("Male")
  val female = Value("Female")
}

object EmailType extends Enumeration{
  val personal = Value("Personal")
  val work = Value("Work")
  val other = Value("Other")
} //object
```

With this I can create a list of strings representing the enum with

```
Gender.values.toList.map(_.toString)
```

or

```
EmailType.values.toList.map(_.toString)
```

I would like to abstrat that to a single method like this

```
def enumToString(values: <type here>): List[String] = values.toList[_.toString]
```

the types I get from the enums are

```
val v1: Gender.ValueSet = Gender.values
val v2: EmailType.ValueSet = EmailType.values
```

I don't see how to abstract this two types to create that generic function showed above. Is there any abstraction posible for this?

Comment: Using `path dependent type` seems fine to me, inspired by Aleksey. `def enumToString(values: Enumeration#ValueSet): List[String] = values.toList.map(_.toString)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to pass `values` then this would work:

```
def enumToString(values: Traversable[Enumeration#Value]): List[String] =
  values.toList.map(_.toString)

scala> enumToString(Gender.values.toList ++ EmailType.values.toList)
res1: List[String] = List(Male, Female, Personal, Work, Other)
```

Comment: Thanks! What's the point of Traversable? I compiled `Enumeration#ValueSet` and it seems the same.

Comment: `ValueSet` works fine when passing a single value set generated by Enumeration but this becomes problematic: `enumToString(Gender.values ++ EmailType.values)` because ValueSet is sorted and requires an implicit ordering to maintain sorted state. I picked a less restrictive type to allow for that.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
def enumToString[E <: Enumeration](e: E) = e.values.toList.map(_.toString)
```

and use it like that:

```
enumToString(Gender) //List(Male, Female)
enumToString(EmailType) //List(Personal, Work, Other)
```